# Order of includes with standard libraries and local headers

Tags: c++, file-io, std, fstream

I'm generating bitmap file. The program compiles every time but depending on order of `#include` at some point, it gives me good or corrupted .bmp file.
It is from a tutorial and all the file are [here](https://github.com/caveofprogramming/advanced-cplusplus/tree/master/WritingABitmap/src).

My structure is as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bitmap.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Bitmap bitmap(800, 600);
    bitmap.write("test.bmp");
}
```

#### Bitmap.h

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class Bitmap {
private:
    int m_width{0};
    int m_height{0};
    unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> m_pPixels{nullptr};
public:
    Bitmap(int width, int height);
    bool write(string filename);
};
```

#### BitmapFileHeader.h

```
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
#pragma pack(2)
struct BitmapFileHeader {
    char header[2] { 'B', 'M' };
    int32_t fileSize;
    int32_t reserved { 0 };
    int32_t dataOffset;
};
```

#### BitmapInfoHeader.h

```
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
#pragma pack(2)
struct BitmapInfoHeader {
    int32_t headerSize{40};
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t planes{1};
    int16_t bitsPerPixel{24};
    int32_t compression{0};
    int32_t dataSize{0};
    int32_t horizontalResolution{2400};
    int32_t verticalResolution{2400};
    int32_t colors{0};
    int32_t importantColors{0};
};
```

#### Bitmap.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Bitmap.h"
#include "BitmapInfoHeader.h"
#include "BitmapFileHeader.h"

using namespace std;

Bitmap::Bitmap(int width, int height): m_width(width), m_height(height), m_pPixels(new uint8_t[width * height * 3]{ }) {}

bool Bitmap::write(string filename) {
    BitmapFileHeader fileHeader;
    BitmapInfoHeader infoHeader;

    fileHeader.fileSize = sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + m_width * m_height * 3;
    fileHeader.dataOffset = sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader);

    infoHeader.width = m_width;
    infoHeader.height = m_height;

    ofstream file;
    file.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
    file.write((char *)&fileHeader, sizeof(fileHeader));
    file.write((char *)&infoHeader, sizeof(infoHeader));
    file.write((char *)m_pPixels.get(), m_width*m_height*3);
    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

Now when in `Bitmap.cpp` it's in this order everything works fine. When I change the order so that `#include <fstream>` is last, it still compiles with no errors but generates corrupted file.
`BitmapInfoHeader.h` and `BitmapInfoHeader.h` are just holding a struct each with some `int32_t` variables in it and don't use `fstream` at all.
Why it is the case?

Comment: Probably a bug in one of the `Bitmap*.h` header files.

Comment: `#pragma pack(2)` if included before the standard headers will cause corruption as this will change the layout of already built (standard) libraries.  You should reset the packing to default ASAP after changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in BitmapInfoHeader.h

```
// issue #1:  There is no guard to prevent re-entry into you header.

#pragma once   // this should fix that, you can also place a classic 
               // #ifndef / #define / #endif guard, as advised by the 
               // C++ Core Guidelines  
               // https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines 

#include <cstdint>
using namespace std; // Issue #2: 
                     // NEVER place a "using namespace std;" in a header 
                      // file.  BTW, it is not even needed for this
                      // file to compile.
                      // And NEVER place a "using namespace ...;"
                      // in the global namespace in a header file. 

// issue # 3.  Any pack pragma MUST be preceded by a push, like this:

#pragma pack(2)                // <-- This pack pragma breaks all include
                               // files that will follow this one.

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)                // use pack(1) to signify full packing,
                               // so when someone else reads your code, 
                               // they won't need to read the whole 
                               // struct definition, to figure out 
                               // what it is you are trying to
                               // accomplish. 

struct BitmapInfoHeader {
    int32_t headerSize{40};
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t planes{1};
    int16_t bitsPerPixel{24};
    int32_t compression{0};
    int32_t dataSize{0};
    int32_t horizontalResolution{2400};
    int32_t verticalResolution{2400};
    int32_t colors{0};
    int32_t importantColors{0};
};

//  After a #pragma(push), don't forget to restore the original 
//  packing, otherwise, you are violating the One Definition Rule.
//  If you do not restore, everything after including this file
//  will exhibit undefined behavior.  

#pragma pack(pop)
```

The file Bitmap.h also has some of the same problems.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. This is getting a bit outside my knowledge but why does not including `#pragma pack(pop)` violates the One Definition Rule? I tried to read some [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) but the examples sometimes include it sometimes not and I don't quite get it

Comment: The other headers are library headers.   Some of the libraries are already compiled, with definitions using the default packing, while your application has definitions with a different packing.  This results in having effectively 2 different definitions for affected structures, one in the pre-compiled static or dynamic library, and a different one in your modules using the structs.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell for sure with no [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But very often when order of includes breaks compilation, it is caused by at least one header fails to include all of its dependencies. In that case, if another header that includes the missing dependency happens to be included before the broken header, it causes the bug to be hidden.

Edit regarding the added code:

If you move the standard header below `#pragma pack(2)`, you break the standard class definitions. You should always push and pop the packing pragma in headers.

Comment: I linked the files as I'm not sure how to shorten them (it's a small repo). It seems the problem is in `Bitmap*.h` files as stated by @Elijay but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Jarartur `I'm not sure how to shorten them` Remove something. If the problem persists, remove something more. If another problem appears or problem resolves, then revert the removal. Repeat until there is nothing to remove.

Comment: I tried to delete as much as I can for it to work but it's still pretty long. For future reference is it ok to post fragmented code like that on stack?

Comment: @Jarartur It should be complete i.e. not require additions, and it should reproduce the problem and it should be as short as possible. All of those greatly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @Jarartur The pragma pack issue mentioned by Richard Critten probably causes problems.